# How to remove Wordpress Virtual Robots.txt that keeps overriding my root robots.txt?

Tags: seo, plugin-wp-seo-yoast, robots.txt, google-xml-sitemaps

So here is the issue. I am trying to remove the virtual robots.txt file in a wordpress site. I realized this was generated with a plugin (xml sitemap plugin) prior to me working on the site.

Here is what I have done. I generated a new robots.txt file, uploaded and ensure it was on the root. Unfortunately, it doesn't show up, it is as if the virtual one is overriding the actual root robots.txt. I can't even use a speed tool to analyze the site. Any help is much appreciated, thanks!

*NOTE Plugins I have related to this are Yoast SEO plugin and Google Sitemap Generator by Arne Brachold.

Answer (score 1):

Okay, after digging into various areas, I noticed I have a security plugin that is blocking these changes. Problem solved by whitelisting, :) in case anyone else has this issue, check your security settings.